# Why method .options does not work on select

Tags: javascript, select

Why property .options does not work on select which is selected by DOM method querySelectorAll but only with getElementById? I need to use querySelector.

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('.current .od select #mySelect');
sel.options
```

*return: undefined*

```
var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect');
sel.options
```

*return: list of options*

Comment: `.options` is a *property*, not a *method*.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, not a single element, and `NodeList` instances don't have an `options` property.

To get a single element, use `querySelector` (no "all"):

```
var sel = document.querySelector('.current .od select #mySelect');
sel.options
```

Or of course, if at some point you want to be dealing with a list, index into it:

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('select');
sel[0].options
// ^^^
```

---

Side note: Unless you want to get back `null` if the `#mySelect` element is in a different part of your document, there's no reason at all for all of those parts of that descendant selector. Just `document.querySelector('#mySelect')` will have the same result, as will `document.getElementById('mySelect')` (but it'll be *much* faster, not that that usually matters).